# If block elements are not supposed to go in inline elements, how come we put block elements in anchor (<a>) elements?

Tags: html

Why do we nest block elements inside of `<a>` if `<a>` is inline and block elements are not supposed to go in inline elements?

I was expecting for block elements to not go in the `<a>` tag, per the guidelines.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#technical_summary and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#transparent_content_model

Answer (score 3):

The [%inline](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#inline) and [%block](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#block) categories were how HTML 4 organised most elements in HTML.

15 years ago, HTML 5 was released. It is more nuanced, not least because it no longer tries to express the rules in the form of an SGML DTD.

[The a element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) has a content model of:

> [Transparent](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#transparent), but there must be no [interactive content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#interactive-content-2) descendant, `a` element descendant, or descendant with the `tabindex` attribute specified.

The means that if the `a` element's parent allows a (for example) `div` element as a child, then so does the `a` element.

Comment: "It is more nuanced, not least because it no longer tries to express the rules in the form of an SGML DTD" says who? The concept of "transparent content" is only defined and implemented to the extent that additional elements are merely accepted *anywhere* below `a` elements depending on the context/parent of `a`. However, it won't work with tag inference such that a parent's non-trivial content model is (partially) enforced/inferred within `a`. The same can be had using SGML inclusion exceptions (and in fact, is what has been done for HTML5 DTDs).